# jqGrid doesn't add search params to url

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I'm trying to use the `filterToolbar` search option.
Unfortunately the search string with parameters isn't added to the url.
In debug I see that this line is executed:

```
590 if(!bsr) { $($t).jqGrid("setGridParam",{search:sd}).trigger("reloadGrid",[{page:1}]); }
```

`sd` is true in my case.

I see that the values that need to be sent to the server are stored in a variable called `sdata`, which is not sent. I also see that the `postData` filters has the right data in it, but it's not sent.

I also noticed that `$t.p.searchurl` is undefined.

This my jqGrid init (sorry for the mess):

```
grid_options = {
                altclass: "grid-altrow",
                altRows: true,
                autowidth: true,
                beforeSelectRow: edit,
                datastr: datastr,
                datatype: datatype,
                height: "100%",
                hidegrid: false,                
                multiselect: true,
                multiselectWidth: 45,
                onPaging: do_page,
                onSortCol: sort,
                pager: "#pager",
                rowNum: ROW_NUM,
                sortname: "zone",
                url: url.toString(),
                gridComplete: grid_complete,
                jsonReader: {
                    page: page,
                    records: records,
                    repeatitems: false,
                    root: root,
                    total: total
                },
                prmNames: {
                    addoper: null,
                    deloper: null,
                    editoper: null,
                    id: null,
                    nd: null,
                    npage: null,
                    oper: null,
                    order: null,
                    page: null,
                    rows: null,
                    search: null,
                    sort: null,
                    subgridid: null,
                    totalrows: null
                },
                colNames: [
                    "Entry Id",
                    "Zone",
                    "IP Address",
                    "Netmask",
                    "Description"
                ],
                colModel: [
                    {
                        hidden: true,
                        index: "id",
                        name: "id"
                    },
                    {
                        editable: true,
                        editoptions: {
                            value: zone_map
                        },
                        edittype: "select",
                        index: "zone",
                        name: "zone"
                    },
                    {
                        editable: true,
                        editrules: {
                            required: true
                        },
                        index: "ip",
                        name: "ip"
                    },
                    {
                        editable: true,
                        editoptions: {value: netmask_edit_options_value},
                        edittype: "select",
                        index: "netmask",
                        name: "netmask",                        
                        stype: "select"
                    },
                    {
                        editable: true,
                        edittype: "custom",
                        index: "comment",
                        name: "comment"
                    }
                ]
            };
            grid.jqGrid(grid_options);              
            grid.jqGrid("filterToolbar", {
                searchOnEnter : false,
                stringResult: true,
                beforeSearch: function(e) {
                    debugger;
                }
            });
```

Any help please?

Comment: could you show us your jqgrid setup code?

Comment: all that in `grid_options` and not a single comment? Your maintainer is going to hate you.

Comment: @Raynos actually i'm the maintainer :) and yep, i would really like to hate the person who wrote this but he's really nice and he's paying :)

Comment: I think i found what's wrong - I noticed a strange &[Object object] param was added to the url so i figured the postData was appended as is. Instead i used serializeGridData to correctly append the values.

Comment: However i don't understand what this isn't happening automatically as in their example code..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eventually we used the solution of manually serializing `postData` on `serializeGridData` postback (after removing `stringResult: true` from the options).

I'm not 100% satisfied because we still don't know why this isn't happening out of the box as it should, and have a suspicion that something's still not 100% right in the configuration.

So I'm not accepting this answer, maybe someone will do better :)

**Edit**: Accepting this since no other solution was found.